# mysql "distinct query" from 3 table performs slow on big data

Tags: mysql, distinct

Here is three table, order, order_record, pay, with near 2300000 records.

there will be more than 1 record in pay table when giving 1 order_id, so I need to use DISTINCT to remove repeated result

now I need to get distinct data from those three table join on order_id, the example query sql below:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT (a.order_id)
    a.order_id,a.user_id
    b.boss_order_id,
    c.pay_id,

    FROM order a
    LEFT JOIN order_record b ON a.order_id = b.order_id AND b.is_delete IN (0,1)
    LEFT JOIN pay c ON a.order_id = c.order_id AND c.is_delete =0  WHERE 1=1 AND a.is_delete IN (0,1)
    ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

this query will takes plenty of time.
then I change to use "GROUP BY":

```
SELECT

    a.order_id,a.user_id
    b.boss_order_id,
    c.pay_id,

    FROM order a
    LEFT JOIN order_record b ON a.order_id = b.order_id AND b.is_delete IN (0,1)
    LEFT JOIN pay c ON a.order_id = c.order_id AND c.is_delete =0  WHERE 1=1 AND a.is_delete IN (0,1)
    GROUP BY a.order_id
    ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

this time the query takes 122 seconds.

Is there any faster way to implement?

Comment: Did you set a indexing on the columns?

Comment: Please, add your tables structure (with indexes) and also the explain plain of your queries.

Comment: The second query is invalid, because you are selecting non aggregate columns.  And `DISTINCT` often uses `GROUP BY` as an implementation, so the two should behave similarly.  The above comment about indexing is relevant.

Comment: @FreedomPride yes

Comment: @JorgeCampos sorry, I can't give the structure. and the plain of my queries is to query limit number of orders's data which stored in order/order_record/pay table, ordered, without duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `left join`.  Hence, you can do:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.user_id, orr.boss_order_id, p.pay_id,
FROM (SELECT o.*
      FROM order o
      WHERE o.is_delete IN (0, 1)
      ORDER BY o.id DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) o LEFT JOIN
     order_record orr
     ON o.order_id = orr.order_id AND
        orr.is_delete IN (0, 1) LEFT JOIN
     pay p
     ON o.order_id = p.order_id AND
        p.is_delete = 0 
WHERE 1=1 AND o.is_delete IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY o.order_id
ORDER BY o.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

You are using `GROUP BY` incorrectly, because you have unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: thx a lot! It works, I got the key from your answer: get the limit number records in table order then do join query on table order_record and pay, which I did join query before ordering and limiting the result.

Comment: Here is another question, what if I want to add `orr.boss_order_id>'xxxx'` before `limit 10` ?

Comment: @halfdark . . . Add it into the second `on` clause, where the `orr` already has conditions.

Comment: I mean before this.` (SELECT o.*
      FROM order o
      WHERE o.is_delete IN (0, 1)
      ORDER BY o.id DESC
      LIMIT 10
     )`, because this sql has already limit first 10 records in table order

Answer (score 0):

Another approach let a where clause do most the work:

```
select ...
from order
left join order_using using (order_id)
...
where
order.order_id < (select max(order_id) from orders order by order_id limit 10) ...
limit 10
```

The final limit 10 is weird though as you may get partial records from an order if you drop the group by.  I.e. you probably want to drop it and and just put a limit orders table.  With the group by means you will a random data from table b and c unless you use aggregate function to tell mysql which of the row values you want.